# Submitting a Web-to-Case form from another domain

Tags: form, web2case

We have a Force.com site on a subdomain: help.website.com. On the Force.com site is a form, which creates a case when it is submitted (Web-to-case I believe). The case is created by an Apex class associated with the page the form is on.

We'd like to move the form to our main site, website.com. We still want the form to submit to Salesforce, and create a case.

Does anyone know how to do this most easily? I can only think of two options: API integration or iFrame.

Comment: In which technology is your website built ?

Comment: Yeah I'll also supports integration here. Though u can Sfdc. OOB api to create cases.

Comment: @MarufBagwan: I think it's on a CMS platform. I'd imagine the integration would be done with Javascript in an HTML page.

Comment: @AnkitKhandelwal: Could you rephrase? Not sure I understand.

Comment: Did you validate that the fields in the current HTML match with the assigments rules that you should set up to assign the case? Here is more information too: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.faq_cases.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your wed-to-case form on most of the websites you just need your org id which will be present in the html code generated in web to case generator.
or simple you can create a vf page for cases and upload it to salesforce site, now you can use this site in iframe.
Calling api is not a efficient choice .

Comment: Thanks! I added the web-to-case HTML (generated using the web-to-case HTML generator) to a different domain (personal site), and tried submitting several times. The form seems to submit successfully, and I am redirected correctly, but no case/contact is created in our sandbox.

Do you know if there is additional configuration that needs to be done? It doesn't mention additional setup in this web-to-case help article: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-case.htm